# After XResizeWindow, X11 is not updating the WindowAttributes

Tags: c++, x11

I am trying to resize a window and get an image using X11 in my cpp program. Though, I can't seem to figure out how to update the window attributes with the new width and height.

When calling XResize, my window does resize on my system, but when calling XGetWindowAttributes, the width & height variables are still the original values.

I have tried remapping my window, searching for my window again after resizing, keeping the updated width and height attributes in variables instead of getting window attributes (this crashes the application when trying to call for a SubImage). Currently, if I keep the window with the original values, when the resized window is larger than the original, the overflow of my image is cut off.

Here is the snippet I am testing with, I am using an instance of alacritty as my test window:

```cpp
void SomeFunction(int w, int h){
  std::cout << "Expected: " << w << " : " << h << std::endl;
  XResizeWindow(m_display, *m_window, w, h);

  XWindowAttributes attributes;
  XGetWindowAttributes(m_display, *m_window, &attributes);
  std::cout << "Actual: " << attributes.width << " : " << attributes.height << std::endl;
}
```

Output:

```
Expected 853 : 480
Actual: 800 : 600
```

Answer (score 0):

X11 is a client/server protocol.

XResizeWindow() sends a "pretty please, can I change this window's size" message to the X server.

Your current window manager has a secret arrangement with your X server, a handshake agreement of sorts. Any time any X client wants to change the visibility ***or size*** of its windows, the X server will [forward the request to the window manager](https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/xlib-programming-manual/9780596806187/ch16s02.html), which has the final say on this subject matter.

So, the "pretty please, can I change this window's size" message gets forwarded to the window manager, for its deep thoughts along these lines. Meanwhile, you asked for your window's current attributes, and discover that your window's size if exactly what it's always been.

When the window manager rubber-stamps the request, only ***then*** does your window's size change, and [you will get a `ConfigureNotify` message (`Configure` event), that tells you your window's new size](https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/events/window-state-change/configure.html).

In other words, you should ***never*** ask for your window's size or position. You will be ***notified*** any time your window's size or position changes, whether that came about in response to your request or to the user manually dragging or resizing your window.

Comment: I have found a solution that does work. If I use my own resize variables after calling for the resize, even after the window is resized, these variables do cause a crash.

Answer (score 0):

[Here](https://github.com/Ofthemasses/VimVentures/blob/3a7935a199f6f62677f5e4b6db5d2808621e415b/src/VimEmulator.cpp#L125-L195) is my current working solution to this issue.

(NOTE: The linked repository is under the AGPL License)

The solution I came to still involves finding the window again, similar to below. Though, it is important to use ConfigureNotify, as mentioned by @SamVarshavchick. You **MUST** wait for your resize event to be recieved. Else, when searching for the window, the result may be the original as the window resize is still being processed.

Deprecated Answer:

I have fixed the issue.. the windows width and height attributes do not update automatically. An explanation on why this is I cannot provide, but finding the window again does update the attributes.

Fix:

```cpp
void SomeFunction(int w, int h){
    std::cout << "Expected: " << w << " : " << h << std::endl;
    XResizeWindow(m_display, *m_window, w, h);
    m_window = this->findWindowByName(m_rootWindow); // Find the window again
    XWindowAttributes attributes;
    XGetWindowAttributes(m_display, *m_window, &attributes);
    m_xImage = XGetImage(m_display, // Update the image we are working with
            *m_window,
            0,
            0,
            attributes.width,
            attributes.height,
            AllPlanes,
            ZPixmap);
    std::cout << "Actual: " << attributes.width << " : " << attributes.height << std::endl;
}
```

I don't like this solution for two reasons.

- Spending resources on finding the window again.
- Calling XGetImage is high cost, it saves a copy of the image in the library which does not free until the program ends. My program primarily uses XGetSubImage to get around this.

Comment: This only works until the window manager decides to reject the resize request, for some reason, and only because your `findWindowByName` likely involves several client server round trips that do not complete before the window manager does its job. If the window manager gets busy with something, you'll be right back where you started. This solution will not work reliably.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Do you recommend doing a ConfigureNotify check, then performing this window search?

Comment: ConfigureNotify gives you your window's new size, as part of the message, as I explained in my answer. No need to search for anything.

Comment: @SamVarshavchik Okay, thank you for the explanations :) I'll try implement this.